# my while loop only take the first value even if it redefined in arduino

Tags: arduino

hello i try to make an interruption in my arduino code to execute only one time a part of it. i use 2 while loop, the first is suppose to detecte when i press a button and the second when i release it. between the two the code i want to execute only one time for one press.

but even if the condition of the while is good it don't want to stop.

[my serial monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CAAX.png)

my code :

```
void loop()
{
    long button =  cs_4_6.capacitiveSensor(5);

    while(button < 1000)
    {
        long button =  cs_4_6.capacitiveSensor(5);
        Serial.println(button);

        Serial.println("not ok");
    }

    if(nbButton[3] == 0)
    {
        nbButton[counter] = 1;
        counter++;
    }

    else
    {
        int nbButton[] = {0, 0, 0, 0};
    }


    while(button > 1000)
    {
        long button =  cs_4_6.capacitiveSensor(5);
        Serial.println(button);                  // print sensor output 2
        Serial.println("ok");

    }
    delay(50);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring `long button` each time in your `while` loops. As you are already declaring it at the beginning of your `loop` there is no need to do it at any other place. The `while` loops are taking your first declaration, which is not changing, whereas the `Serial.print` takes the new one defined only in the `while` loops.

In your two `while` loops change `long button =  cs_4_6.capacitiveSensor(5);` to `button =  cs_4_6.capacitiveSensor(5);`

Hope it helps,